# Cookie to remember css stylesheet preference

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a cookie which will remember the css stylesheet preference.

I switch stylesheets as:

```
function swapStylesheet(sheet){

    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);

}
```

And call it from buttons:

```
<a button class="Button" onclick="swapStylesheet('DayStyle.css')">Light</a>
        
<a button class="Button" onclick="swapStylesheet('NightStyle.css')">Dark</a>
```

So it changes the href to the css file of choice, but on refresh it changes back to default.
Any way to create a cookie to remember the href preference?
And can it be for all of the site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Comment: To define a cookie: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the localStorage of your browser since the use of cookies is mostly intended for reading data server-side (but you could still use cookies if you really want to).

Obviously you could also use sessionStorage, though the preferred theme won't be available after the tab/browser is closed because, as the name suggests, a sessionStorage is not kept when the session is closed. This would defeate the purpose of remebering a user preference..

Approach with localStorage:

When the user selects the style, you can:

```
function swapStylesheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
    localStorage.setItem('stylesheet', sheet);
}
```

And when initially loading the page you could use the `<body onLoad ="checkLS()">` function to check if localStorage is set and apply style:

```
function checkLS () {
    let sheet = localStorage.getItem('stylesheet');
    if (sheet) {
        swapStylesheet(sheet){
    };
}
```

This way the users preferred stylesheet/theme is automatically set even if the browser was closed between visits..